# getPath() and Spaces in Java

Tags: java, file

I encountered a problem with getPath() recently.

my code looks something like this:

```
File path = new File(Main.class.getResource("/worlds/").getPath());
File[] files = path.listFiles();
```

The Problem now is, that if there is a space somewhere in the Path to the Main class, `path.listFiles()` will return `null`. If there is no Space, everything works fine.

if i print the path to the cmd, i see that every space is replaced by an `%20`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that. A [resource URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) returned by [getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) isn't necessarily a file on the file system, which is what [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) represents.

Comment: Maybe, but i cant see a better way read the content of a directory, relative to the Path where the program is executed

Comment: `new File("./worlds").listFiles()`

Comment: @MasterCassim: I'd like to see proof of that. The error described in the question is related to improperly decoding a URL and trying to use it as a file path. My suggestion doesn't use a URL, so how can it cause the same error?

Comment: @Simiil there's no 'maybe' about it, it's a fact, and the fact that you can't see a better way doesn't change it.

Comment: Code: System.out.println("Using new File(./worlds)!");
   path = new File("./worlds"); 
   
   System.out.println("Path = "+path);
   File[] files = path.listFiles();
   System.out.println("Files = "+files); Output: Using new File(./worlds)!
Path = .\worlds
Files = null

Comment: @MasterCassim: That works fine. You'll only end up with "files == null" if there's no `worlds` in your current directory. To see where it's looking for the directory, add `System.out.println("Looking in " + path.getAbsolutePath());`. Create a worlds directory at the path where it's looking, and try again.

Comment: Yeah; but that was the problem the whole time. It is looking in the false directory. The right one is D:/***/target/classes/worlds which is returned by `Main.class.getResource("/worlds/")`; but your code returns D:\***\.\worlds. The problem is to always get the right location without hardcoding it.

Comment: @MasterCassim: No, that wasn't the problem at all. The problem was that converting a URL to a String put `%20` in place of all the space characters due to URL encoding. As the OP said, there was no problem if there were no spaces in the path.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: You suggested to use `new File("./worlds")` but that doesn't look in the right directory what was the reason to use getResource() because it return the right one. Therefore your suggestion can not be used. I know what the problem is ;)

Comment: @MasterCassim: Actually, the OP's first comment was that he's trying to get the "content of a directory, relative to the Path where the program is executed", which is what my suggestion does.

Comment: Program executed means (in this case) where all files are located (resources; class files; ...) which will be executed. We need to knwo where the class files are located. Otherwise we can't access non-java files for our project.

Answer (score 13):

that is not the correct way to convert a URL to a File.  try this instead:

```
new File(Main.class.getResource("/worlds/").toURI());
```